# Does calling a method from a specific thread automatically make it run on a seperate core?

Tags: java, multithreading

For example, I make two threads:

```
ExampleThread t1 = new ExampleThread();   
ExampleThread t2 = new ExampleThread();
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Then whatever is in the run() in each thread is finished. Yet, I know I can still call, say,

```
t1.exampleMethod();
```

AFTER it's run() is completed. Does this work on it's own core?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it will run on the caller thread.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you don't want to extend Thread but rather implement Runnable, and in fact doing so may help clear up some of your confusion, because even though t1 extends a Thread, your calling a method will **not run on that thread**, the t1 thread, but rather will run in the thread that it was called from.

Also note that "after a Thread's run is complete", the Thread no longer runs -- it is done, gone, kaput.

Answer (score 1):

```
t1.exampleMethod();
```

This is a normal method call and it will be executed in the same thread.(**No new thread**)

```
t1.start();
```

This creates a new thread which starts executing `run()` method and after completion of that,it's work is done.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `t1.exampleMethod()`, even `t1.run()` will not run in `t1` thread.

They will just behave like any other method call, nothing special unless you call `t1.start()`

Only `t1.start()` will run it in that thread.

Comment: Well, `t1.start()` will run in the calling thread too, but what it does is create a new thread that then does a bunch of stuff.